# Which one is the correct/standard mathematical notation?

Tags: soft-question, notation, math-history

I want to learn that, which one is the correct/standart mathematical notation?

> $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}}$ or $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)?$

What is the standard mathematical notation?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $(0, \infty)$ mean different things.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R^+$? Otherwise the two are different.

Comment: Ohh, sorry ,I fixed the question.

Comment: Many define $\mathbb{R}^+$ as $(0,\infty)$. The same way that cilantro and coriander are the same herb.

Comment: Both are correct. Neither is "standard".

Comment: Both are standart notation?

Comment: The first one definitely looks more consistent (although requires $\mathbb R^+$ to be defined at some point).

Comment: I thought it was a special reason to prefer the second.

Comment: Either one is fine.  However, I prefer $(0,\infty)$ as not everyone knows what $\mathbb{R}^+$ means. Furthermore, the "+" superscript sometimes denotes *nonnegative* values, such as when we are dealing with nonnegative lattice cones, which could potentially lead to ambiguity as to whether $\mathbb{R}^+$ contains zero.

Comment: Which one is "this notation" that seems strange to you?

Comment: @bof $(0,\infty)$. I've never seen it before.

Comment: I'm guessing that the strangeness is in specifying $\infty$ as the "end" of an interval?